# Event handler only runs once, but outputs multiple times?

Tags: java, event-handling, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

I am trying to make something similar to a text adventure, but with a GUI instead of through a console. I want to be able to print stuff to a Jlabel multiple times (it would be switching to a different string constantly).

I got it to work, but only once. What I'm trying to do with the printEnter(String toPrint) method is print toPrint to the GUI. As you can see, the printEnter method is called four times, but only the text "one" is printed to the GUI. In the console of Eclipse, though, it prints the user's  input four times. If I added a fifth printEnter method, it would print it five times, etc. Because of this, I know it runs four times, but it only updates the GUI once.

My goal is to make it so whenever the player presses enter, the text would switch to a predefined string (like the "one, "two", "three", and "four" that I have it printing)

Can someone please let me know how to simply switch the text on the gui when enter is pressed? I'm new to event handlers so there's a big chance I'm just doing something completely wrong. Thanks in advance.

My entire program:

```
//Init scanner
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Default text (appears when program first runs)
static JLabel textInputLabel = new JLabel("textLabel", SwingConstants.CENTER);
static JLabel textShown = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
static JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel("logoLabel", SwingConstants.CENTER);

//Name of window
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Broken");

//JTextField edit and unedit, respectively
static JTextField editTextArea = new JTextField("Type here", SwingConstants.CENTER);

static String input;

private static void Window() {

    //Text color and background color of print area, respectively
    textInputLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
    logoLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    textShown.setForeground(Color.yellow);

    frame.getContentPane().add(textInputLabel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);

    //Makes window and sets its properties
    textInputLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 450)); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    frame.requestFocus();

    //Text input setup
    frame.getContentPane().add(textShown, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
    frame.add(editTextArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(logoLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Background and text color of input area, respectively
    editTextArea.setVisible(true);
    editTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
    editTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);
    editTextArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 30));

} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Window();
    doStuff();
}

public static void doStuff() {
    logoLabel.setText(""
            + "<html> <center> "
            + "<font face=\"verdana\" size=\"20\"> <br> "
            + " Broken <br> "
            + " Program <br>"
            + " <font size=\"4\"> &ensp </font> ______________________ "
            + "</font>"
            + "</center> </html>");

    printEnter("one");
    printEnter("two");
    printEnter("three");
    printEnter("four");

}

public static void printEnter(String toPrint) {
    editTextArea.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              input = editTextArea.getText();
              textShown.setText("<html> <center> <font size=\"20\"> " + toPrint + " </font> </html>");
              System.out.println("User inputted: \"" + input + "\"");
           }
        });
}
```

Comment: Dump the `ActionListener` from `printEnter`, just call `setText` of the `editTextArea`.  Probably a better option would use `JRadioButton`s

Comment: I deleted the action listener but now the actionPerformed method is broken. How do I fix this? https://gyazo.com/77253fdd32ccd7dc0e2ada158f202ac7

Comment: Okay. Set up a single use `ActionListener` for the `editTextArea` which takes the current text from the field and does what ever you want with it.

Comment: Okay, I did that and now it just prints "three" to the GUI instead of going through each of the 3 calls and waiting for enter to be pressed before continuing. https://gyazo.com/8a4bb54e9caa44e24e16085539900f5a

Comment: You're general approach is wrong - sorry, but it is. Instead of trying to use a `JTextField` in this way, present all the options to the user `JOptionPane` can do it or use a series of `JRadioButton`s instead

Comment: I thought it might have been. I'll try out those options tomorrow. Thanks for your help.